# Алгоритм поиска самого длинного пути

Tags: алгоритм, c++

Имеется некая матрица MxN, заполненная случайными числами, в том числе и отрицательными. Нужно найти самый длинный путь из ячейки А в ячейку Б. Подскажите какой алгоритм использовать для этого, или его придется разрабатывать самому?

Comment: Тут нужно уточнить две вещи:
1) Что есть путь?
2) Что есть длина пути?

Comment: я так понимаю, что Вы имеете ввиду задачу о максимальном потоке, на википедии есть алгоритмы решения:
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C7%E0%E4%E0%F7%E0_%EE_%EC%E0%EA%F1%E8%EC%E0%EB%FC%ED%EE%EC_%EF%EE%F2%EE%EA%E5#.D0.A0.D0.B5.D1.88.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.8F

Comment: Я имею ввиду что надо идти из ячейки А в ячейку Б по другим ячейкам, причем ячейки не должны повторяться, сумма чисел  всех пройденных ячеек от А до Б будет являтся результатом пути